# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]

Tags: android, api, gson, retrofit2, pojo

I am facing issue while calling the api. Can anyone help me the resolve the exception.

```
   JSON FORMAT:
[
[
{“id”:”1”},
{“id”:”1”}
],[],[]
]

MODEL:
public List<Data> data;

 Public class Data{
@SerializedName("id")
public String id;
}

CALLING:
Call <List<IndividualListModel>> indiList(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Comment: The error message explains your problem, your JSON begins with an array indicated by "[" and not with a begin object identifier "{", fix your JSON string, then GSON should not have problem converting it.

Comment: @P.Leibner can't change the json format..can you please let me know the model class and calling changes required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the root element, the JSON that you receive doesn't have a `List<Data>`. It has `List<List<Data>>` since there are some arrays, nested inside another array:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "1"
    }
  ],
  [],
  []
]
```

Comment: Made changes in model class   public List<List<Data>> data;  Still getting same error.      Do I need to remove list from Call <List<IndividualListModel>>

Comment: Its done by changing List<List<IndividualListModel>>